# How does a micro interpret high freq rf signals from an antenna

Tags: rf, clock, cpu

If an antenna is receiving a frequency higher than the clock speed of the cpu, then how is the cpu able to interpret the data being received by its antenna?

Comment: The CPU isn't what interprets the high frequency stuff.

Comment: Perhaps because there is an RF transceiver between the antenna and the CPU.

Comment: I don't know any Micro that can read RF directly.  If you do provide a link.  There are plenty of RF modules that can encode or decode RF and pass the data on at a lower frequency the micro can handle.

Comment: Are you confusing the data rate and the carrier frequency? Consider an FM radio. It transmits audio frequencies (<< 20 kHz) at 88 to 108 MHz. Paraphrasing your question we get, "How can we hear radio stations when they transmit at 88 to 108 MHz?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. There are other dedicated circuits that process (amplify and demodulate/digitize) the signal from the antenna, and the results are presented to the CPU at a rate that it can handle.

There are some chips that have this RF circuitry integrated onto the same die as the CPU. For example, in the [ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32) block diagram, the CPU is in the orange block in the center, while the RF circuitry is in the purple box in the upper left. There are additional dedicated circuits in the top center that perform further processing of the baseband signals before the CPU gets them.

[image: ESP32 block diagram]